# convert sample java code to ruby - switch webview for hybrid app

Tags: ruby, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to use ruby language and having an issue to switch the context to webview. found solution in Java that I need to put in ruby, please could you help understand how this works in Ruby?

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        for (String context : contextNames) {
            if (context.contains(contextName)) {
                driver.context(context);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using appium_lib, I use set_context for change context between 'NATIVE_APP' or 'WEBVIEW'. doc: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/appium_lib/8.0.1/Appium%2FDevice%3Aset_context

And for list contexts I use: available_contexts. doc: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/appium_lib/8.0.1/Appium/Device#available_contexts-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

We created a full appium suite and use the methods below to switch the context for us:

```
def set_native_context
$driver.set_context($driver.available_contexts.first)
@context = 'Native_App'
end

def set_webview_context
$driver.set_context($driver.available_contexts.last)
@context = 'WebView'
```

end